# Content-type header is always the same while testing koa routes with supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, supertest, koa-router

I have an application build with `koa` and `koa-router`. When testing routes with `supertest` I face a problem, that `content-type` response header is always `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

```
const app = koa();
router
    .get('/img', function *(next) {
      this.type = 'image/png';
      // this.set('Content-Type', 'image/png'); 
      // this.set('content-type', 'image/png');
      this.body = renderImage();
    });

app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());


describe('Routes', () => {

  it('should handle /tiles/*/*/*/* requests', (done) => {
    request(http.createServer(app.callback()))
      .get('/img')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Content-Type', 'image/png')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        console.log(res.res.headers);
        if (err) return done(err);

        expect(renderImage).to.be.called;
        done();
      });
  });
```

How test fails:

> Error: expected "Content-Type" of "image/png", got "application/json; charset=utf-8"
>       at Test._assertHeader (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:215:12)
>       at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:247:11)
>       at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:148:18)
>       at Server.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:127:12)
>       at emitCloseNT (net.js:1525:8)

What is logged via `console.log(res.res.headers)`:

```
{ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'content-length': '2',
date: 'Wed, 09 Mar 2016 10:15:37 GMT',
connection: 'close' }
```

Yet, if I do a request from the browser to the provided route, `content-type` header is changed correctly:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:334
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Wed, 09 Mar 2016 10:15:01 GMT
```

Neither `this.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');` nor  `this.set('content-type', 'image/png');` changes the situation.

Is it a bug? Has anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things to try:

Is `this.body = renderImage()` actually setting the body to `null` or `undefined`?
When looking through the Koa.js code for the [response object](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/lib/response.js#L133), it looks like koa is removing the `content-type` header if the body is set to `null` or `undefined`.

Is the return value of `renderImage()` an object? If so, is it a buffer or stream? When the `body` is set koa tries to detect what the content-typeof the response should be. If it is not a `string`, `Buffer`, or `stream`, koa [forces](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/lib/response.js#L174) the `content-type` header to be `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks! I've stubbed `renderImage` function so that it returned an empty object: ``renderImage: sinon.stub().returns({})`. That was why the header was removed. I wonder why it is not mentioned in the specs.